# Getting SIGABRT while using vector

Tags: c++, vector, runtime-error, c++17

```
int maxOccured(int L[], int R[], int n, int maxx){
    
        // int v[maxx]={0};
        vector<int> v(maxx);
        for(int i=0; i<n; i++){
            v[L[i]]+=1;
            v[R[i]+1]-=1;
        }
        int max=v[0];
        int res=0;
        for(int i=1; i<maxx; i++){
            v[i]+=v[i-1];
            if(v[i]>max){
                max=v[i];
                res=i;
            }
        }
        return res;
        
    }
```

here in my code if I am using an array of same size it is working fine but while using a vector I am getting an error of

```
Abort signal from abort(3) (SIGABRT)
```

Comment: *if I am using an array of same size it is working fine* -- I bet it isn't "working fine".  More than likely, you are going out-of-bounds of the array, and going out-of-bounds is undefined behavior.  If you used `at()` instead of `[ ]` to access the vector elements, it will probably show what mistake you're making, as you will get an `std::out_of_range` exception thrown instead of a SIGABRT.  Also, please post a [mcve], as we have no idea how you're calling this function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are few things you should be absolutely sure of:

1. n <= max (to avoid out of bounds runtime error)
2. 0 <= L[i] < n and 0 <= R[i]+1 < n for all values of i from 0 to n-1(provided condition 1 is satisfied). (Again to avoid out of bounds runtime error)
3. maxx is not too large (of the order of 10^5 or 10^6) otherwise your vector won't get enough storage to store its elements and your program will crash.